# Getting ROLLUP or sum of Count() in a new filed in mySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, rollup

i have a table where i need count for a column and then group it by other column, and then get the total value of count per group in a new field beside the count.
i am adding some data to explain exactly what i want:

```
   CREATE TABLE tablename (
  ID INTEGER,
  NAME VARCHAR (10),
  TAG1 INTEGER,
  TAG2 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES 
(1, 'A', 1, 2),
(1, 'A', 2, 5),
(1, 'B', 1, 4),
(1, 'D', 3, 7),
(1, 'C', 5, 6),
(2, 'A', 1, 2),
(2, 'A', 2, 5),
(2, 'A', 2, 5),
(2, 'B', 1, 4),
(2, 'D', 3, 7),
(2, 'C', 5, 6),
(3, 'A', 1, 2),
(3, 'A', 2, 5),
(3, 'B', 1, 4),
(3, 'D', 3, 7),
(3, 'A', 1, 2),
(4, 'A', 2, 5),
(4, 'B', 1, 4),
(4, 'D', 3, 7),
(4, 'D', 5, 6),  
(4, 'C', 5, 6);
```

i have used query:

```
select ID
     , ifnull(NAME,Concat(ifnull(NAME,'TOTAL - '), ID)) NAMES
     , sum(case when (TAG1>0 and TAG2>0) then 1 else 0 end) Cnt 
  from tablename 
 group 
    by ID
     , NAME with rollup;
```

what i get is :

```
ID NAME Cnt 
1   A    2
1   B    1
1   C    1
1   D    1
1  Total 5
2   A    3
2   B    1
2   C    1
2   D    1
2  Total 6
3   A    3
3   B    1
3   D    1
3  Total 5
```

and what i want is sum() field beside the count field

something like

```
ID NAME Cnt Sum
1   A    2   5
1   B    1   5
1   C    1   5
1   D    1   5
1  Total 5   5
2   A    3   6
2   B    1   6 
2   C    1   6
2   D    1   6
2  Total 5   6
3   A    3   5
3   B    1   5
3   D    1   5
3  Total 5   5
```

any suggestions???

Comment: Why do you need the value both in a column and a row?  Plus, your final result doesn't look correct.

Comment: I can make do with out a rollup in the query if i can get the sum column like i illustrated. The last result i have displayed is how I want the query result to be(without rollup if helps).

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: i havent set any primary key in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual request.  You cannot get what you want using `sum()` for the third column because of the `rollup`.  So, use a subquery:

```
select t.ID, coalesce(NAME, concat('TOTAL - ', t.ID), t.ID)) as NAMES,
       sum(t.TAG1 > 0 and t.TAG2 > 0) as Cnt,
       max(tt.sumcnt) as `sum`
from tablename t join
     (select id, sum(TAG1 > 0 and TAG2 > 0) as sumcnt
      from tablename t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
group by t.ID, t.NAME with rollup;
```

Comment: worked as a charm mate ...Thank you very much...i know what i wanted seemed unusual , but needed this type of data for creating some visuals.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.Thanks!